# MongoDB: Updating indexed filed with WiredTiger storage

Tags: mongodb, indexing, wiredtiger

Does updating a indexed field have any impact in wiredTiger?
I was going through below question.
Q. Adding the index { a : 1 } can potentially decrease the speed of which of the following operations? Check all that apply.

A. db.collection.update( { b : 456 }, { $inc : { a : 1 } } );

I believe above answer is correct for MMAPV1, but in wiredTiger there should not be any impact, since wiredTiger uses an immutable document identifier rather than storing location address. Can someone confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer is 'yes'.

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/#indexes) clearly states:

> Adding an index has some negative performance impact for write operations.

Since WiredTiger does not support in-place updates, executing this command will effectively duplicate the existing documents found by the filter condition (`{ b : 456 }`) except for the given change (`{ $inc : { a : 1 } }`) which will be reflected in the new documents, too. In a second step, the storage space allocated for the original documents will be freed up.

With MMAPv1, the space requirements for the updated documents would not differ from the original ones, so an in-place update happens.

However, regardless of the storage engine used, a change to an indexed field requires the affected index(es) to be updated, too. For MMAPv1, "only" the key of the index leaf changes in your case - the document stays at the same location. In the case of WiredTiger, both the key and the document location will need to be updated in the index.